# Determine all the subgroups of the dihedral group $D_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Is there an algorithm for finding all of the subgroups of $D_{15}$? Also, is there a formula for finding the size of that subgroup?

Not sure where to start with finding all the subgroups of $D_{15}$ so any tips would be helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf) by Conrad. Theorem 3.1